# Does fork() work differently on Ubuntu in Comparison to other Linux Distribution?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, unix, gcc

Ok, so here is the initial Code I was working with on an Ubuntu 17.10.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
   printf("Demonstrating fork():\n");
   fork();
   printf("After fork():\nProcess Id is %d\n", getpid());
}
```

So at this stage I found out the output to be : [image: Initial Output]

So yeah I executed twice to confirm it. But later I noticed that in Online GCC Compilers and on RedHat in my College Campus, The output is pretty different:

[image: other gcc output]

Now as per my knowledge, the fork() creates another instance of the process it is called from. But in Ubuntu it seems it copies from the point where it is introduced in the code, and rather the whole Process. To detect it, I slightly chaged the code to :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    fork();
    printf("Demonstrating fork():\n");
    printf("After fork():\nProcess Id is %d\n", getpid());
}
```

And to my surprise I was right on my observation with the output :

[image: After Change Output]

So can anyone confirm this, and explain me why is this happening, or just a bug on my system ?

Comment: One question. Did this happen with the exact same code that you posted?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Exactly my point but this is showing extremely different output and I need a clear Answer why so. I have copied this exact code on more than 10 Systems of my Classmates and the Outputs were all as expected, except on Ubuntu. I have only 1 machine to test it on.

Comment: Oh, and enable compilers warnings. The UB might be caused by the way you have declared `main()`. I don't remember whether it's UB or not, but it's certainly wrong to write `void main()` with standard compliant compilers.

Comment: Yes, that exact same code.

Comment: I change void to int, and still the same anomaly

Comment: @SoumyadeepGhosh It appears that someone answered correctly, but still please don't do `void main()` ever again.

Comment: I am executing it on my *arch*linux and it worked as expected, seems like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48731272/1983495) is the explanation. And it doesn't involve `fork()` behaving differently on different systems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But later I noticed that in Online GCC Compilers and on RedHat in my College Campus, The output is pretty different.

It has to do with the user-space buffer `printf()` uses.

If the program is executed at the terminal and the output is not redirected to a file, then the buffer is flushed by `printf()`ing `\n`.

The online version does not flush the buffer by `printf()`ing a `\n` because it is using another flushing policy (e.g.: the output is probably being redirected to a file).

Comment: This makes sense.